# iOS SpriteKit - Touch at a specific location, want node at specific zPosition

Tags: ios, touch, zposition

I have a project where when I tap I check to see if the tap is on a specific node. If it is then I create a new SpriteNode at that position that is only visible for .1s before being deleted. I want to be able to spam tapping on the screen but with that current check the node that I end up tapping on is the new SpriteNode that I've created.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {    
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

        if (node == shutdahellup){
            [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"shut-da-hell-uh.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO]];
        }else if (node == hotdamn){
            [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"hot-damn.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO]];
        }else if (node == wafflewednesday){
            [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"waffle-wednesday.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO]];
        }else if (node == damnwaffle){
            [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"get-a-damn-waffle.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO]];
        }
        [self createFace:touch];
    }
}
-(void) createFace:(UITouch *)touch {
    SKSpriteNode * face = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"shane.png"];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    face.position = location;
    face.zPosition = 100;

    [self addChild:face];

    SKAction * wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.1];
    SKAction * remove = [SKAction removeFromParent];

    SKAction * sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[wait, remove]];
    [face runAction:sequence];
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!